Selecting two subsets of points, minimizing internal distance and maximizing external distance
Given n points, each with one of two assigned classes, I am looking for an efficient method to select two subsets, one per class, with k < n points. In the simplest terms, the selection should follow the criteria:

The distance between points within a selected subset should be minimal.
The distance between points from different subsets should be maximal.

I have found several methods to select a minimum or maximum distance, but not both for subsets with class constraints. I assume this is a known optimization problem, but I lack the terms to search for it. This solution should also be scalable to higher dimensions.
It is okay if the solution is not optimal but a good approximation.
I am looking forward to any help!

Use Greedy optimization

start with k random points per class
minimize internal distance , by iterative swapping points to reduce total within subset distance
maxmize enternal distance by choosing fathest points between subsets during swaps

here are details --
To solve your problem efficiently, use the Greedy Algorithm:

Randomly select $k$ points from each class $A$ and $B$.

Minimize the sum of pairwise distances within subsets $S_A$ and $S_B$.

Maximize distances between points in $S_A$ and $S_B$.


Swap a point in $S_A$ (or $S_B$) with one outside if it improves:
[
C = \alpha \cdot \text{SumInternalDistances} - (1 - \alpha) \cdot \text{SumExternalDistances}
]
where $\alpha$ balances compactness vs. separation.

Stop when no further improvement is possible.


For scalability:

Use KD-trees for faster distance computation in high dimensions.
For a good approximation, tune $\alpha$ empirically.

Tools:
Python with Scipy (distance.cdist), NumPy, or Gurobi for exact Mixed-Integer Programming (MIP) solutions.  sorry for any bad writing or inconvenieces and hope this helps , also i would be thankful if someone edited my answer
